# UnityでUIのボタンを押したときに実行する処理をボタンとは別のオブジェクトにアタッチしたいのですがどうすれば良いですか？

Tags: c#, unity3d

コード例
オブジェクトにアタッチするスクリプト
今はボタンを押すと "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object" というエラーが出ます。

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Johanshin : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Animator animator;
    private Button button;

    void Start()
    {
       
    }

    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    public void OnButtonClick()
    {
        実行したい処理
    }
}
```

Comment: まず、別のオブジェクトにアタッチしたスクリプトは動作していますか？
OnButtonClick メソッドに、Debug.Log("OnButtonClick"); を記述して、メソッドが呼ばれているかどうか確認してみてください。

Comment: 記述してみたところ、 'Debug' is an ambiguous reference between 'UnityEngine.Debug' and 'System.Diagnostics.Debug'というエラーが表示されました。

Comment: すいません。解決しました。しかし、ボタンを押しても表示されませんでした。

Answer (score 0):

まず、実行したい処理を記述したスクリプトを任意のオブジェクトにアタッチします。
ここでは、ButtonManager という空のオブジェクトに、ButtonManager.cs をアタッチしています。

[image: スクリプトを任意のオブジェクトにアタッチ]

次に、ボタンの On Click() の項目に、スクリプトをアタッチしたオブジェクトをヒエラルキーから選択、ドラッグアンドドロップ操作で設定します。
(*) スクリプトを設定するのではなく、オブジェクトを設定します。

[image: スクリプトをアタッチしたオブジェクトの設定]

No Function の項目から、実行させたいメソッドを選択します。

[image: No Function の項目から、実行させたいメソッドを選択]

これで、ボタンクリック時に、選択したメソッドが実行されます。

Comment: 解決しました。ありがとうございます。